# Questao sobre números quadrangulares(quadrados perfeitos)

Tags: c++

preciso fazer um algoritmo que leia um número inteiro qualquer e verifique se ele é quadrangular. Se for, mostrar os próximos 10 quadrangulares depois dele. Se não for, informar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
    int valor, soma=0, fator, i; 
    int ii;

    cout << ("Informe um numero: ");
    cin >> valor;

    for(i=1; soma < valor; i+=2)
        soma += i;
    
    (fator = ((i+1) / 2) - 1);
    i++;

     
    if ((fator*fator) == valor)  
    cout << (" eh quadrangular\n");
else cout << ("nao eh quadrangular");
  

    
    return 0;
}
```

não to conseguindo montar a estrutura de repetição para repetir os 10 números a frente do digitado.

Comment: Ao invés de `sqrt(numero)*sqrt(numero)==numero`, por que não verifica se `sqrt(numero)` é um inteiro?

Comment: acabei de tentar, acho que nao da certo pq o numero que eu digito sempre eh inteiro, o que eu quero eh que mostre na hora de mostrar os numeros na tela, mostre so os que tem raiz exata

Comment: Mas não é verificar se o número informado é inteiro, mas sim a sua raiz quadrada.

Comment: acho que eu consegui, acabei de atribuir a raiz quadrada do numero a uma variável inteiro. Agora só preciso fazer com que os números se repitam, tenham a raiz exata.